# Alternative to Taply

Tags: software-recommendation

I've relied on Taply, a simple music player, since at least Leopard. The program is 32 bit and won't run on MacOs after Mojave. There is no 64 bit version of the program, which is no longer in development.

Is there a 64 bit alternative?

Comment: What makes it special? What feature set do you miss in other players? There are a myriad music players to choose from.

Comment: It does one thing, and one thing only: play an mp3 music file when invoked. Nothing else. It doesn't try to phone home, load libraries or do anything else except play the song selected.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the blurb on https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/15190/taply it would appear to do exactly the same as just tapping the spacebar in Finder…

[image]

The only difference being that you can't work in Finder whilst it's doing this, but you can work in any other app at the same time.
I typed this answer, took & added the screenshot, then posted, all whilst the song was playing.

Comment: Indeed, you can't do anything else. Taply does not have this restriction.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the Terminal, try

`afplay foo.mp3`

and

`qlmanage -p foo.mp3`

The last one does exactly what the Finder does when you press space on the file, with the benefit that you can continue use the Finder while the song is playing.

Comment: The problem is that the music often has long file names, this solution works but it is not as practical as Taply. BTW, the Windows program Billy has the same functionality as Taply.